# Regex for multiple delimited items of unknown length

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a really simple set of strings:

- `These are the items 17, 28`
- `These are the items 9`
- `These are the items 5, 8, 207`
- `I shouldn't match, but here's an arbitrary number to make things hard 14`

I'm trying to create a regex that will give me the digits as a list of items:

```py
r = re.compile(r'These are the items (?:(?P<item_numbers>\d+),?\s*)+')
```

I thought that wrapping the capturing group I was interested in within a non-capturing group would work, but when I match any string with multiple values (say our `17`, `28` example):

```py
input_string = 'These are the items 17, 28'
match = r.match(input_string)
match.groups()
> ('28',)

match.group('item_numbers')
> '28'
```

Is there a way I can do what I want with a single regex or is this a task not well suited to a regex?

Comment: `r"These are the items ((\d+,?\s?)+)"`, that will extract the numbers at the end of the line.

Comment: You could do this in two steps `if string matches "^These are the items" then use \d+ to get the digits`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findall` is probably what you're looking for. Try this out for size:

```
r = re.compile(r'(?:(?<=\D)|(?<=\A))(\d+)(?=\D|\Z)')
re.findall(r, input_string)
```

Comment: My question is definitely an unintentional dupe, but this actually works fairly well with some adjustment. Thanks